# How to take screenshot in selenium ide

Tags: selenium

Using Selenium IDE Firefox plugin, I want to take automated screenshots. The test script contains these steps

```
Command                          Target                               Value
open      /?gfe_rd=cr&ei=GNCWU-6BCujV8geh_4C4Bg&gws_rd=ssl  
click                              id=gbqfq     
type                               id=gbqfq                      software testing
click                               id=gbqfb    
captureEntirePageScreenshotAndWait  F:\Screenshots\
```

The log shown this error:-

```
[error] Unexpected Exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code:       0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFileOutputStream.init]" nsresult: "0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED)" location: "JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986" data: no]. toString -> function toString() { [native code] }, message -> Component returned failure code: 0x80520015 (NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED) [nsIFileOutputStream.init], result -> 2152857621, name -> NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED, filename -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js, lineNumber -> 2986, columnNumber -> 0, inner -> null, data -> null, location -> JS frame :: chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/selenium-api.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 2986
```

please resolve this error

Comment: See http://fijiaaron.wordpress.com/2011/05/20/capture-screenshot-log-results-with-selenium-ide/.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Screenshot on Failure plugin. It grabs a screenshot of the HTML at the point of failure as per it's name. Here is the link:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screenshot-on-fail-selenium/

This plugin integrates directly with Selenium so you can turn it on or off through the UI itself. To install it, open the link with a FIREFOX browser and click the "ADD TO FIREFOX" link. (For those not familiar with the Selenium IDE, it only plugs into Firefox.)

Once installed properly you will see a  Screenshot on Fail icon next to the "FAST - SLOW" slider. Toggling this button on turns on the feature, toggling it off means that snapshots won't be taken. By default it is off when the IDE is launched. The tiny down-arrow next to it allows you to view the screen shot / failure report(s).

Comment: Your comment that link-only answers can become invalid is true, but this isn't a link-only answer. From this answer, even if the link doesn't work, we know that a plugin exists called Screenshot on Failure. We know what the plugin does and how it can help if we are able to find it. See Your Answer is in Another Castle: When an Answer is not an Answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: Thanks ArtOfWarfare and l3arnon. I've provided some more detail in any case.